# Controlling access to the graphics card in X.Org

Tags: linux, opengl, 3d, x11, xorg

I am looking for a way to control which applications have access to use the GPU and video memory when using X.Org on Linux.

**The setup:**

I am developing an embedded Linux system where several 3D games are started on boot. I am starting all the games such that they are present in memory which makes it possible to switch quickly between them.

The idea is that only 1 game is visible at a time. This is done by mapping the windows of the active game and unmapping the windows of the inactive ones. I.e. "minimizing" the windows of the inactive games.

**The problem:**

The performance of the active game is not optimal, and so it seems that the inactive games are still taking up resources on the graphics card even though their windows are unmapped from X.Org.

**What I have tried so far:**

My current solution is to suspend the inactive games and only have the active one being resumed. This is however not optimal since I would like to do IPC communication with the inactive games as well.

**The question:**

How can I disallow a Linux application access to the graphics card, such that their draw calls to the graphics card are simply ignored.

Answer (score 2):

If your games start slow, it's time to optimize that.

If a game is inactive and not using GPU resources the driver will eventually swap all OpenGL resources out of GPU memory, so when the game resumes it will experience some noticable delay, when the OpenGL driver is swapping resources back into GPU meory.

Just unmapping a window is not enough, you also have to stop the main game loop, so that they don't consume CPU memory.

> How can I disallow a <s>Linux</s> X11 application access to the graphics card, such that their draw calls to the graphics card are simply ignored.

With current generation X11 and drivers: Switch to another VT than the X11 server it runs on. You can start any number of X11 servers you like, but only one can be active on a display VT at any given time.

Note that given the right driver architecture and drivers also inactive VTs may access the GPU, but right now this is not the case.

Comment: The games must be shown within 1 second after selecting it, so we can't rely on loading the game data from disk. From our experiments so far, swapping resources back into GPU memory is fast enough to adhere to this requirement.

Comment: Consumption of CPU cycles is handled using [cpulimit](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit).

Comment: Having multiple X servers could be a solution, but this gets messy to handle for the windowmanager in regards to overlay windows, popups, etc.

Comment: @uldall: The windowmanager on the main "desktop" will not "see" the game window at all. Make a small helper window as stand in for the main fullscreen game, and when that gets restored chvt to the game X server. In the game itself provision a hotkey to chvt back to the main desktop, which will trigger the stand-in window to minimize.

Comment: @uldall: However be advised that switching the active X server eventually will swap out all GPU data, so when switching back to the game there may be a noticeable delay again if your game can't cope with that. Personally I'd suggest to redesign the game engine to be functional and responsive even if not all OpenGL resources are loaded already.